# Filtering GPS jitter when standing still?

Tags: ios, gps

I am working on an iOS app with tracking. I have implemented Kalman smoothing in order to present a pleasing path. This is working pretty well at this point.

I am having a bit of trouble dealing with the user-not-moving case though. When the user IS moving we get very good reads back from the CLLocation Manager. And even when a reading is a bit off the Kalman algorithm takes care of it.

When standing still the CLLocation Manager delegate is still receiving "accurate" locations. They have good accuracy, not an unbelievable speed. Looking at the screen with human eyes it's clear that the user is standing still with all these points just scattered around. Some points very close and a few of them far out.

I have tried setting the CLLocationManager property pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically but it doesn't seem to be working that well. It doesn't always stop when it should and there have been difficulty restarting the tracking again as the antennas are powered down.

So I'm looking to keep the tracking on the whole time but I want to filter out the jitter in post processing. So I determine programmatically that the user is stopped and discard (or ignore) all locations until the user is moving again.

I'm not really sure how to go about this, what algorithm is appropriate to achieve something like this?

Comment: if you do solve this, please let Niantic know about it

Comment: Hey dantastic, I am currently having the same issue I am trying to solve. Would you tell me what you did to improve the standing-still sections?